# How to insert a percent symbol in url in beamer?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, urls

I found when I use the `article` class and `hyperref` package, the % can be printed by `\href{url}{text}`but things changes when I use beamer, for example

```
% Works fine
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \href{www.google.com}{google}
  \href{http://www.google.com%some site}{google}
 \end{document}
```

and

```
% Doesn't work
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test page}
  \href{www.google.com}{google}
  \href{http://www.google.com%some site}{google}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I include the % in the url link? Thanks a lot.

Comment: doesn't escaping (`\%`) work?

Comment: Thanks. `\%`  works. But I want to know why it failed in beamer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to do its work, `beamer` has to absorb a `frame` environment's contents at once. This has the consequence that `\href` cannot perform its duty of changing the nature of `%`, because when the contents is absorbed, TeX does not interpret commands and `%` is still the comment character.

You have two ways to go around the issue:

- escape `%` into `\%`
- use `\begin{frame}[fragile]`, that's recommended whenever the frame contains verbatim material.