# How to link a URL with a % symbol in it?

Tags: urls, links

I tried `\href{http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf}{url}`
but the `%` sign in the url ruins it, and TeXShop interprets the rest as a comment.

Comment: Are you using [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer)? Otherwise, within the standard document classes, your usage works as-is with [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: ...see [How to insert a percent symbol in URL in `beamer`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334187/5764)

Answer (score 4):

Try with the below code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\url{http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of setting the option `dvips`?

Comment: If you want use TeX->dvips->PS2PDF then use this option "dvips" else use "[pdftex]" for PDFLaTeX usage

Comment: You should mention the purpose of the option(s) up-front, in the body of answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `\` (backslash) before all the `%` symbols and it will work fine with your code.
:)

Comment: This will probably solve it everywhere, although it might not even be needed.